# Create a dynamic XML href in PHP with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, jquery-mobile, simplexml

I'm trying to create a link based on a URL variable using only the last five digits of its respective line of XML data.

For example, if the XML `link` is `http://events.stanford.edu/events/213/21389` how can I create this link `a href="e/?i=21389`?

Here's my [page](http://bit.ly/jSnxMb), [XML](http://bit.ly/kFuQXt) and code:

```
    <?php
    // Build the XML file path, using URL variable $c (above)
    $c = $_GET['c'];
    $p ="http://events-prod.stanford.edu/xml/byCategory/";
    $e = "/mobile.xml";
    $file = "$p$c$e";   

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $xml->title; ?></h1>
<a href="http://stanford.edu/group/homepage/cgi-bin/m/" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right">Home</a>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
<?php // Only display if there are events ?>
<?php if (isset($xml->Event->title)) { ?>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <?php foreach($xml->Event as $event) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $event->link; ?>">
            <?php if ($event->Media->url != null) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $event->Media->url;?>" alt="<?php echo $event->title;?> thumbnail" />
            <?php } ?>
                <h3><?php echo $event->title; ?></h3>
                <p><strong><?php echo $event->beginDate; ?> at <?php echo $event->beginTime; ?></strong></p>
                <p><?php echo $event->locationText; ?></p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php echo '<p>There is currently nothing scheduled for ', $xml->title, '.</p>';?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Ryan can you provide an example of $c ?

Comment: @Ryan I can answer your question easily if you just gave me an example of $c. $c is a part of your URL to get the XML data. I can put in random $c values, but it returns random XML data, some that don't have the needed id's for me to properly get what I want to complete this task.

Comment: @FinalForm - $c is determined by static HTML links from the previous page (http://bit.ly/k5q4Hc). In the example page above $c is "0" for Arts.

Comment: @Ryan k, I'll let you know if I have any other questions. I will start work now on it.

Comment: @Ryan If you do <?= "hello world" ?> Are you able to see the output? I want to see if your php.ini file is configured a certain way.

Comment: @Ryan If you do <? echo "hello world"; ?> are you able to see the output? Again, for a similar reason.

Comment: Yes, both <?= "hello world" ?> & <? echo "hello world"; ?> output "hello world".

Comment: @Ryan Done, tested it on my box and it works. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using short tags, because I think you'll agree it's easier now to read the code as oppose to before.

```
<?
    $controller ="http://events-prod.stanford.edu/xml/byCategory/";
    $category_id = $_GET['c'];
    $category_id = 0;            
    $xml = "/mobile.xml";

    $url = $controller . $category_id . $xml;       
    $xml_object = simplexml_load_file($url);
?>

<div>
    <h1><?= $xml_object->title ?></h1>
    <a href="http://stanford.edu/group/homepage/cgi-bin/m/" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right">Home</a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">    
    <? if (!empty($xml_object->Event->title)): ?>        
        <ul data-role="listview">
        <? foreach($xml_object->Event as $event): ?>        
            <li>    
            <?
                $pattern = '/[0-9]+$/';
                $matches = array();
                preg_match($pattern, $event->link, $matches);
                $my_link = 'e/?i=' . $matches[0];
            ?>

            <a href="<?= $my_link ?>">                                
                <? if (!empty($event->Media->url)): ?>
                    <img src="<?= $event->Media->url ?>" alt="<?= $event->title ?> thumbnail" />
                <? endif; ?>

                <h3><?= $event->title ?></h3>            
                <p><strong><?= $event->beginDate ?> at <?= $event->beginTime ?></strong></p>                    
                <p><?= $event->locationText ?></p>
            </a>
            </li>
        <? endforeach; ?>        
        </ul>            
    <? else: ?>        
        <? echo '<p>There is currently nothing scheduled for ', $xml_object->title, '.</p>'; ?>            
    <? endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that you can't use just `<?` with IIS.  Besides, isn't it considered bad to not specify a full `<?php`?